# Doctrine 2: GROUP BY field DESC error

Tags: mysql, doctrine-orm

When i try execute in Doctrine 2.1 with DQL sentence:

> SELECT t FROM \Test\TestingBundle\Entity\Testing t **GROUP BY t.date DESC**

Doctrine 2 returns an exception saying it was found an unexpected DESC. This is one of the most practical methods of MySQL to sort the results returned by **Group by**.

Comment: Why don't you just add an `ORDER BY` clause instead?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately it seems that Doctrine does not support using desc in group by clause.
If there are performance issuse and you cannot use order by, then consider using a native query.

Answer (score -1):

I think you missed `order by`:

```
      SELECT t FROM \Test\TestingBundle\Entity\Testing t 
      GROUP BY t.date ORDER BY t.date DESC
```